# Call function in dynamically created row in Polymer

Tags: jquery, vaadin, polymer-3.x, polymer-2.0, vaadin20

I am adding a row dynamically using a template. While adding the row, I also want a `on-change="addTotal"` function on Amount column. Whenever the Amount column of newly added row changes, it should call `addTotal()` function that adds all the values of rows and does total. However, using this code, it does not call the `addTotal` function.

```
addRow() {
    var template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = '<div class="tr" ><div class="td" >' +
        '<vaadin-text-field theme="field-description"></vaadin-text-field></div><div class="td"><div class="td" >' +        
        '<vaadin-text-field theme="field-amount" class="totalcheck" on-change="addTotal"></vaadin-text-field></div><div class="td" ></div>'
 
    var fragment = template.content;
    this.$.Table.insertBefore(fragment, this.$.subTotalRow);

}

addTotal(){
//this adds all values of Amount column
}
```

I have tried addEventListener using a class name "totalcheck" in addRow() function, but this is undefined too.

```
document.querySelector('totalcheck').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
            console.log(e.detail); // true
        })
```

Comment: Could you clarify the versions? The tagged selection is slightly confusing. Vaadin 6 for one has been out of support for years, and I'm not sure if we ever did anything Polymer-related with it... Do you mean the Vaadin 7 compatibility package within Vaadin 8?

Comment: I am using vaadin 20.0. Is there a way to add a function on-change="addTotal" in template.innerHTML for vaadin-text-field?